# Floats interrupt and push back text

Tags: floats, positioning, landscape

I have a

```
\subsection{Subsection}

Text text text

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
...
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:dcspe}
\end{figure} 
\end{landscape}

Other text other text other text

\subsection{Other subsection}
```

The way this renders is though

> Subsection
>
> Text text text
>
> pagebreak
>
> single page with the figure
>
> Other text other text other text
>
> Other subsection

How can I get the "Text" to be followed by "Other text"?

Answer (score 6):

Use `sidewaysfigure` from `rotating` rather than `landscape` and `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Subsection}

Text text text

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
...
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:dcspe}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

Other text other text other text

\subsection{Other subsection}
\end{document}
```